# Deriving the Center of Mass of a semi-circular disk with cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

**Problem:**

> Derive the Center of Mass of a semi-circular  disk of mass $M$ and radius $R$.

**My attempt:**

$$Y_{CM}=\int ydm$$

Now, $$dm=\sigma dA$$ where $\sigma$ is mass per  unit area.

Converting into Cylindrical Coordinates,$$dA=rdrd\theta$$. Also, $$y=r\sin\theta$$

Hence the integral  can be rewrittenn as

$$\int_0^R\int_0^{\pi}r^2\sin\theta d\theta dr$$

However this Integral gives me the wrong value  of the Y coordinate of  the Center of Mass.

I would be truly grateful for any help  with  this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice, your formula $Y_{CM} = \displaystyle{\int y\ dm}$ is not correct.

the center of mass is given as $$Y_{CM}=\frac{\displaystyle{\int y\ dm}}{\displaystyle{\int dm}}$$ 
Now, substituting the values $y=r\sin \theta$ & $dm=\sigma rdrd\theta$, we get

$$Y_{CM}=\frac{\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sigma r^2\sin\theta d\theta\ dr}}{\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sigma r d\theta\ dr}}$$

$$=\frac{\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{R}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta\right)r^2\ dr}}{\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{R}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta\right)r\ dr}}$$

$$ = \frac{\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{R}\left(2\right)r^2\ dr}}{\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{R}\left(\pi\right)r\ dr}} = \frac{\displaystyle{2\int_{0}^{R}r^2\ dr}}{\displaystyle{\pi\int_{0}^{R}r\ dr}}$$

$$ = \frac{2\left[\frac{r^3}{3}\right]_{0}^{R}}{\pi\left[\frac{r^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{R}}$$

$$ = \frac{4R^3}{3\pi R^2} = \frac{4R}{3\pi}$$

$$\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{\color{blue}{Y_{CM}=\frac{4R}{3\pi}}}$$

Answer (score 12):

The center of mass of a uniform half-disk obviously lies on the perpendicular bisector of the base diameter, at distance $d$ from the centre of the disk. By the [Pappus centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus's_centroid_theorem),

$$ 2\pi d \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}R^2 = \frac{4\pi}{3}R^3, $$
hence $d=\color{red}{\large\frac{4R}{3\pi}}$.

Comment: What is the reason behind the downvote? It looks like a pretty straightforward solution to me.

Comment: Please remember that answers are not designed for the OP only: they serve a community. 
So, if you do not understand a correct answer by your own limitations, or think it is "too advanced" by your personal standards, please do not punish through a downvote the good will to provide a contribute to MSE, but just ignore it.

Comment: Can u please explain how u wrote                
  2\pi d \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}R^2 = \frac{4\pi}{3}R^3

Comment: @RiyaVerma: have you looked at the statement of Pappus' theorem?

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong,are you trying to say semi disks rotated by 2πd create volume of sphere. If it is so, why we need d(com) in 2πd we can take 2πr.

Answer (score -1):

The x-coordinate is at $(0,0)$ and y-coordinate will change

$$\bar{y}=\frac{\displaystyle{\int y\ dm}}{\displaystyle{\int dm}}$$
plugging in values and solve
The answer is clearly

$\bar y=\frac{4r}{3\pi}$

Comment: This is a repeat of Harish Chandra Rajpoot's answer.